# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net

Estoy intentando compilar un proyecto .net que he clonado desde bitbucket,pero despues de configurar el framework y los archivos webconfig y package.config y correr el proyecto, siempre me marca este error

[image: error]

he intentado algunas soluciones que marcan en ingles, perooo, no he encontrado una solucion para el codigo de error "0x80070057". Hasta ahora no he logrado compilar el proyecto

estoy utilizando visual studio en windows 8.1

Comment: Mira este enlace a ver si te puede ayudar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148543/what-does-hresult-0x80070057-mean-and-why-is-my-program-crashing?lq=1

Comment: intenté la solución, pero nada aun